# Decreasing left padding in mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a `div` where I give some padding for all size device. But one of my client wants to decrease left padding when browsing through mobile phone. Here is the code -

```
.price-form {
background: #438bc7 none repeat scroll 0 0;
padding: 19px 30px 10px 75px;
color: #ffffff;}
```

I need to be padding is `padding: 19px 30px 10px 25px;` in mobile device.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I used following code

```
@media screen and (min-width : 480px){
.price-form {
    background: #438bc7 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    padding: 19px 30px 10px 25px;
    color: #ffffff;
}}
@media screen and (min-width : 978px){
.price-form {
    background: #438bc7 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    padding: 19px 30px 10px 75px;
    color: #ffffff;
}}
```

UI is perfectly match in laptop but not in mobile device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to have padding `padding: 19px 30px 10px 25px;` on mobile devices, you need to use max-width media query. You can change pixel in max-width according to requirement.

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px){
    .price-form {
        padding: 19px 30px 10px 25px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Media Queries. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) is a good reference.

```
   @media screen and (max-width : 480px){
        .price-form {
            padding: 19px 30px 10px 25px;
        }
    }
```